# Is there a way to check whether a link has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, click, focus, if-statement

I would like to use .focus() to advance my slider to the next screen. I have next and back buttons. If a user clicks the next button, **I do not want** the .focus() function to advance the slider. However if focus is on the next button, I'd like the focus to trigger the next button .click() function.

This is the way I have it now. When I tab and place focus on the next button, the slider advances. When I click the next button, the slider is advanced two times.

```
$(".nextbutton4").focus(function() {
     $(".nextbutton4").click();
});
```

I came up with another version of the focus() function with an if-else statement, but it doesn't work.

```
// This allows a tab advancement to trigger the next action
$(".nextbutton4").focus(function() {
    if (//This is where I would like to check whether the button was clicked) {
          alert('Next Button is Clicked');
          // Do Nothing
    }
    else {
          alert('Next Button Not Clicked');
          $(".nextbutton4").click();
     }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a class when the user clicks the link:

```
$('.nextbutton4').click(function() { $(this).addClass('clicked'); });
```

And then simply check to see if it has the class:

```
// This allows a tab advancement to trigger the next action
$(".nextbutton4").focus(function() 
{
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) 
    {
          alert('Next Button is Clicked');
          // Do Nothing
    }
    else 
    {
          alert('Next Button Not Clicked');
          $(this).click();
     }  
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution, however it doesn't stop the duplication of the advancement during click.

Comment: When a user clicks the next button, focus is applied to the button. It then fires the click function and the focus function.

Comment: It would be better to intercept the click function and call the `nextSlide` function through logic, rather than triggering the actual `click` event...